# Access Alias from Derived Table in Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I like to access an alias phrase from the from clause in a nested subquery statement.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM t1, (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE name = "hello") AS t3 
WHERE t1.name in (SELECT * FROM t3);
```

I know that the example makes generally no sense, but I think, it shows my problem very well.
So I don't know how to access an alias from a FROM-clause in a subquery.

Comment: You can't _select_ from a table alias. Use cte/with clause.

Answer (score 0):

You want `JOIN` :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.col = t1.name
WHERE t2.name = 'hello';
```

You can use also sub-query  :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE t1.name IN (SELECT t2.col FROM t2 WHERE t2.name = 'Hello');
```

Note : `sub-query` will accept only one expression with outer query expression (1 expression specified in outer query).